# How to assign initial value to a String in Android

Tags: android, string, sharedpreferences

i don´t know where i have to setup the initial value of this variable:

```
mySharedPreferences.putStringValue("hello", "400");
```

And it don´t be reset if it is changed every time i open the app.

Thank you!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to do that is to "set" the default value on get method instead of set it on the first start of your app.

```
mySharedPreferences.getString("hello", "400");
```

On this way android checks if there was an value set. If not, it will fallback to the default "400".

Take a look at the documentation:
[https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html#getString(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html#getString(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))

Answer (score 0):

And in application tag

```
   <application
    android:name=".YourApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

In Application's onCreate Method. It is best place. It will be executed when your app is created.

```
public class YourApplication extends Application {

public static Boolean sAppOpened = false;


@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
   //Write your code here
  sAppOpened = true; 


....
}

...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare your SHARED PREFERENCE file name class-wide like this -

`public static final String SHARED_PREFERENCES = "SHARED_PREF";`

You can use this in your `OnCreate` method.

```
SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
editor.putString("key", "value");
editor.commit();
```